# How do I parse MS-DOS time in perl?

Tags: perl, dos

I'm reading a binary file using perl. In the file's headers, there's 4 bytes that represents MS-DOS time. How do I read this time? I'm not familiar with this format.

I've found this for reference: http://www.vsft.com/hal/dostime.htm but I'm still not sure how to read it.

Comment: You will need to `unpack` the raw bytes, then use bitwise `&` and shifts to extract the values (or maybe you could do it directly with `unpack`; it's fairly versatile and intended for precisely this sort of task). See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html

Comment: I did my $dostime = unpack 'l', $data; my $year = 1980 + ($dostime >> 9); but I get the year as 2068586.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

```
sub mst {
  my $msdos_time = shift;
  my @t = map { ord }
          map { pack("b*", $_) }
          map { reverse($_) }
          unpack("A5 A6 A5 A5 A4 A7", unpack("b*", $msdos_time));
  my %d;
  @d{seconds,minutes,hours,day,month,year} = @t;
  $d{seconds} *= 2;
  $d{year} += 1980;
  return \%d;
}
```

This will work if `$msdos_time` is represented in little-endian format which (I believe) is how it would be laid out in memory.

(Clearly the chained `map`-s could be coalesced - I wrote it this way to make it easier to see what was going on.)

Example:

```
print Dumper(mst("\x22\x12\x01\x41"));

# byte 0   | byte 1   | byte 2   | byte 3
# 76543210 | 76543210 | 76543210 | 76543210
#    S...s                                   seconds
# ..m             M..                        minutes
#            H...h                           hours
#                          D...d             day
#                       ..m               M  month
#                                  Y.....y   year
# 00100010 | 00010010 | 00000001 | 01000001

$VAR1 = {
      'seconds' => 4,
      'hours' => 2,
      'month' => 8,
      'day' => 1,
      'minutes' => 17,
      'year' => 2012
    };
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain what those maps do? First it unpacks into binary.. then what? What is A5 A6 A5 A5 A4 A7 for? Why reversed and packed again? I'm trying to compare this against what it says in the link I posted (0-4 bit for second, 5-10 bits for minute etc) and I don't get uses that.

Comment: The `A5 A6 ...` comes from the width in bits for each field: 5 bits for seconds, 6 bits for minutes, etc.
To understand the algorithm, just step through it one function at a time: first print out what `$x1 = unpack("b*", ...)` does; then print out `@x2 = unpack("A5...", $x1)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) because it always wants to start on a byte boundary. Some of these values go across byte boundaries too, so you don't want to deal with individual bytes (although words would work). It's easier to just to mask and shift.

In this example, I set up the masks so I don't have to think too hard about it, then use those to grab the values out of the string. I don't really know anything about the DOS time format, but from what I've read, you have to multiply the seconds by 2 (notice it's only five bits):

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

# seconds   minutes   hours    day    month   years from 1980
#  5 bits    6         5        5       4       7
my $datetime = 0b11011_000011_11111_01100_1011_0001000;

my $parsed = parse( $datetime );
print Dumper( $parsed );

sub parse {
    my( $datetime ) = @_;
    state $masks = make_masks();

    my %this = map {
        $_, ( $datetime & $masks->{$_}[0] ) >> $masks->{$_}[1]
        } keys %$masks;

    $this{seconds} *= 2;
    $this{years} += 1980;

    return \%this;
    }

sub make_masks {
    my %masks = (
        seconds => [ 0b11111,  27 ],
        minutes => [ 0b111111, 21 ],
        hours   => [ 0b11111,  16 ],
        day     => [ 0b11111,  11 ],
        month   => [ 0b1111,    7 ],
        years   => [ 0b1111111, 0 ],
        );  

    foreach my $key ( sort { $masks{$a}[1] <=> $masks{$b}[1] } keys %masks ) {
        $masks{$key}[0] <<= $masks{$key}[1];
        }

    return \%masks;
    }
```

My output is just a hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'seconds' => 54,
          'hours' => 31,
          'years' => 1988,
          'month' => 11,
          'minutes' => 3,
          'day' => 12
        };
```

Comment: near the top, what's `my_unpack`?

Comment: @user5402 - it looks like `my_unpack` should be `parse`

Comment: have a look at my solution which uses `pack` and `unpack`

Comment: I don't understand this code. In make_masks(), what are those values for seconds, minutes, etc (27, 21, 16 11, 7, 0)? In parse(), why is state used instead of my? You said don't use unpack, but then how would I do it when I'm reading a binary file? I get Argument "pM-%M-a>" isn't numeric in bitwise and (&) if I don't unpack. Or am I supposed to unpack as binary?

Comment: @oopy, those numbers are the position of each field in bits.  `state` is used so the masks only have to be calculated once.  You would use `unpack` to convert the 4-byte value to an integer, and pass that integer to `parse`.

Comment: Reading a file and parse the data are different things.